# Trying to get old report model .smdlproj to work in Visual studio 2010

Tags: reporting-services

I have a .smdlproj report model file. When I try to open it in visual studio 2010 it throws an error saying the project type is unsupported. With some research it looks like the last version to support this format was visual studio 2008.

Does anyone know if theres anyway I can upgrade the project, or install anything on 2010 that would make it compatible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They don't open in anything later than visual studio 2008, simple as that apparently.